# Prevent update_checkout from firing mid-typing

Tags: javascript, woocommerce-offtopic

Is there any way to prevent the `update_checkout()` function from firing on the checkout page while a user is typing in the boxes? It seems to be set on some sort of `set_timeout()` where it's firing a couple of seconds after the latest `change` event, but sometimes it removes focus from the current box and so shipping calculations may appear broken if a string is incomplete or malformed.

I don't know if it's relevant, but we're in the process of adding a custom field to the Billing & Shipping info forms so we can allow users to set pickup and dropoff addresses. We're modifying a plugin called Distance Rate Shipping by Automattic.

Anyway, I thought I'd ask because this is the first time I've worked with Woocommerce and I'm not sure where that `change` event originates from. I'd like to set it to `blur` rather than `change` at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while and maybe you don't need this information. But i am having exactly the same problem.
So i have come up with this solution:

```
window.setTimeout(
 function () {
  $('form.checkout').off('input keydown change', '.address-field input.input-text, .update_totals_on_change input.input-text');
}, 0);
```

It removes all "input/keydown/change" events from zipcode and address fields.
I have used setTimeout to call my function asynchronously after all the woocommerce scripts. But to apply my own functionality i need to use some kind of callback inside this function;